# How to set a condition for interval to stop when condition become true in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-promise, setinterval

I want to stop making API calls when a variable become undefined.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Set time interval to update data again and again
    const source = interval(3000);

    if(this.groupId){

       this.subscription = source.subscribe(
          val => this.mrDataService.getGaugeData(this.groupId).then(
             data => {
                if(this.groupId){
                    console.log(data)
                }
             },
             error => {
                console.log('Something Went Wrong')
             }
          )
       );

    }
 }



  ngOnDestroy(){
      this.groupId=undefined;
   }
```

I need to set `this.groupId` to undefined when component is destroyed. When I `console.log(this.groupId)` in the `ngOnDestroy` it prints `undefined` but the interval keep making calls.

The services file:

```
getGaugeData(groupId:any){
    return this.http.get(this.path, {headers: {'tokenid': this.tokenId},params: {groupId: '3133'})
        .toPromise().then(res => {
        return res;
    });
}
```

Comment: Please check https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Thank you this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't misunderstood, you need to unsuscribe the Observable, then, only must call this function.You could use doCheck, called ensure before groupId become undefined, and unsuscribe the susbscription.

```
doCheck() {
  if(!this.groupId) {
     unsuscribe().
  }
}
```